# Can Eloquent model observer access model data that are being affected by the event?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, observer-pattern

I am trying to create an `observer` for an Eloquent model to work as a logger for the changes on that model. I am not sure what parameters are passed to the observer's methods from the model. If the parameters don't include an instance of the updated model, is there another way around it without having to redefine the model class and override the needed methods?

```
class UserObserver{
    public static function saved($user){
        Activity::create([
            "activity-name" => "save",
            "user" => $user->id
        ]);
    }    

}
```

Comment: Since the whole model is passed you should be able to access any method and attribute the model has

Comment: is the whole model passed?

Comment: I think so. Just give it a try using dd and you will see.

Comment: Yeah, you can do whatever you want. However what you should do is use something like **https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/revisionable** or https://github.com/VentureCraft/revisionable

Comment: @ITroubs, I keep getting only "0" for whatever model is updated.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk, I want to implement something like that myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the model is actually passed, my mistake was not adding `user` property to the `fillable` array in the `Activity` model.

usually, I get an exception when my application tries to update fields that are not included in the `fillable` array, but this time I didn't. anybody knows why?

Comment: You get the `MassAssignementException` when an attribute is `guarded`. Otherwise, if it is just not fillable, it is ignored when you call `$model->fill($attributes)` (which is the case also with `create`).